# Trying to find amount of Saturdays that fall on the last day of each month in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, time, rubygems

I am working on a very specific problem. I need to find the number of times that Saturday falls on the last day of each month within a five year time period.

For this example, I need to find those Saturdays from 1/1/1990 to 1/1/1995.

I've already tried the following code.

```
require 'active_support/core_ext' 
require 'date'

beginDate = Date.parse("1/1/1990")

endDate = Date.parse("1/1/1995")

saturdays = beginDate.upto(endDate).count(&:saturday?) && beginDate.upto(endDate).count.end_of_month

puts saturdays
```

Does anyone have any suggestions or pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need any [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) crap here in the first place. Plain [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) would perfectly do.

```
require 'date'
beginDate, endDate =
  Date.parse("1/1/1990"), Date.parse("1/1/1995")
(beginDate..endDate).count do |d|
  d.saturday? && d.month != (d + 1).month
end
#⇒ 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Mobile, so can't test, but something like  `(0..11).map.with_index { |i| date = Date.today + i.months; date.beginning_of_month if date.end_of_month.saturday? }.reject(&:nil?)`

Comment: You can use select instead of map so that you don't have to reject.